# Unity C# NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know, this question was already answered a lot here, and believe me, I've tried so many ways to fix that problem, but it occurs over and over again.

So basically, I'm trying to change e.g. money in my game, from a different script.

But as soon as I click the button, I get this error message. I think I'm doing anything fundamentally wrong here, but it also happens in my score script, but that is still working anyhow... But here is the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Score.ResetScore () (at Assets/Scripts/Score.cs:36)
```

And here are the Scripts that **should** work together.

Script 1:

```
void ResetScore()
    {
        GameManager gamemanag = GetComponent<GameManager>();
        score = 0;
        gamemanag.ResetQuestions();
    }
```

Script 2:

```
public void ResetQuestions()
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }
```

That was the score script because it's a bit cleaner. This doesn't really work as it should as well and I have no Idea why...

I'm posting the full code on pastebin at the end.

Would be great if you could help!

Script 1: http://pastebin.com/raw/qvbFYd3x

Script 2: http://pastebin.com/raw/8gMzaagq

Comment: The only way that that `ResetScore()` can throw a `NullReferenceException` is if `GetComponent<GameManager>()` returns `null`. Which is possible depending on configuration. Which makes me think that the problem isn't in your code, but in your configuration, which isn't part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things going on:

1. (Why are you setting score to 0 if score == 0? You could just leave
   the else away.)
2. In `DisplayScore` you are accessing the `scoreText`
   field. That will throw a **NullReferenceException** if you haven't
   set it in the inspector.
3. In `ResetScore` you are getting the
   `GameManager` instance. The call to `ResetQuestions` will throw a
   **NullReferenceException** if your gameobject that contains the `Score` script doesn't contain the `GameManager` script too.
4. In `Start` of the `GameManager` you could get a **NullReferenceException** if you haven't set any question in the inspector.
5. You have an *off by one* error in your `SetCurrentQuestion`. Basically if there are no questions you are getting a random number from 0 to 0. The only valid result is 0 in that situation. You are then accessing question with index 0. But there won't be one. (That would throw an **IndexOutOfRangeException**)
6. Any of your private [SerializeField] fields could throw a NullReferenceException if it hasn't been assigned in the inspector.

As you can see, many of your statements could result in a **NullReferenceException**. We won't be able to actually tell you where the issue is, because it could be in so many places. You are best off by debugging your code and checking where a variable you are trying to access is null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've changed it in ResetScore to if (score != 0)
            score = 0; So Number 1 is out I guess. I still get the error. I've set the Scoretext everywhere, so number 2 is out as well I guess. I've set questions as well, so number 4 is out as well. Number 5, I've set the range from 0 to the number of all unanswered questions, above I've checked if they were any unanswered questions left, and if they weren't I've refreshed the list. So I don't think that would be a problem. And I don't have any SerializeFields not assigned, so it has to be 3.

Comment: Do you mean with that, that I have to add the GameManager Script to every Game Object that has the Score Script on it? I'd need to fill in the Questions twice then, wouldn't I?

Comment: GetComponent searches the current gameobject for a correct component. If you don't know where the component is you may use the static GameObject.GetComponent<GameManager> wich searches through the scene. I can't test it right now so the method name might be slightly different.

Comment: @thaiten The method is called: "GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameManager>()"

Answer (score 0):

any object can be null...

just check your code:

```
GetComponent<GameManager>();
```

can give you no GameManager,

```
questions.ToList<Question>();
```

or your list is not initialized. Fix it with:

```
 unansweredQuestions = new List<Question>();
```

You need to debug your code directly, or just check to != null